# "Payment failed with google pay. Please retry payment with a different upi app." when we integrated razor pay in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, razorpay

After integrating razor pay in android, Payments are working find with cards and wallets but when we try using UPI it's getting failed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqTfx.jpg)

1. I tested with different live razor pay api key it work find with different one.
2. But payment through card is working fine.
   If you find any solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable upi payments in razorpay dashboard?

Comment: This isn't an answer, if you need to ask something, please comment on the question.

Comment: Yes, I enabled the upi payments in razorpay dashboard.

Comment: @Zero i can't i don't have enough reputation